# Black console screen do not display in magento connect manager

Tags: magento

I'm using magento enterprise 1.9.1.1

In magento connect manager, the black console screen did not displaying.

Do you have any suggestion about this? Thanks

Comment: Enterprise edition? you have Enterprise support to bother :)  why not contact them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on Magento EE, have you considered on contacting Magento Support? I think they will give you the best solution for your problem.

Regards.